# Oracle bind variable not set

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind, sqlplus

I want to use a bind variable to communicate the outcome of a plsql block from within sqlplus (or sqldeveloper) BUT if the block terminates with an unhandled exception then any previous assignment to the bind variable is ignored.

Examples:

```
var testvar varchar2(30)
```

1.

```
begin
  :testvar := 'hello';
end; 
/

print testvar  -- prints hello
```

2.

```
begin
  :testvar := 'hello';
  raise program_error;
end; 
/
print testvar  -- prints null
```

3.

```
begin
  raise program_error;
exception
  when others then
    :testvar := 'hello';
end; 
/

print testvar  -- prints hello
```

4.

```
begin
  raise program_error;
exception
  when others then
    :testvar := 'hello';
    raise;
end; 
/
print testvar  -- prints null
```

So if the block terminates with an unhandled exception then the bind variable is effectively rolled back.
Can this default behaviour be changed somehow so that a bind variable value remains intact if the block terminates with an unhandled exception ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you're out of luck and will need to do something different, like use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` instead.  The [SQL\*Plus User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-82D529C1-ACF3-4A8C-A58C-9CCC6D12AC1D) kind of documents this behavior: "...displays bind variables (referenced in a **successful** PL/SQL block ..."  But hopefully someone else can find a workaround and prove me wrong.

Comment: @Jon Heller I think you're right. Can't think of anything that can be set in the session to change it. This actually stems from an APEX issue where anonymous blocks are manipulating session state represented by bind variables. Any errors are propagated back up to the APEX engine which reads the session state. Except the bind variables were empty. So I went back to basics using sqlplus to interpret the interaction between plsql and bind variables and identified the above behaviour. Can't think of any good reason for it (perhaps there is) but it's so frustrating.